# Material suggestions for a dev about to learn reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

do you have any advice for a dev about to begin learning react js?
all I require would be links to video tutorials and maybe a couple of tips and tricks that could help along the way... it would be really helpful, to beginners everywhere(i think we're all actually beginners, but that's a topic for another day).

Comment: Look at Programming with Mosh or Academind on youtube. But it's up to you what you want to learn exactly and what your knowledge is already. Best is you start with following the video tutorials and learn on the go.

Comment: The React docs are a fantastic place to start. [Getting Started](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: thanks... I'll check that out right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start is with the official [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), [step-by-step guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), and [general documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

I'd recommend using [Create React app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) as instructed on the official site to create your first react application to mess around with.

Once you get pretty familiar with the library, you can find an abundance of free YouTube tutorials and StackOverflow threads to get deeper into specific subjects that still remain confusing to you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and it would be a great start. On the other hand, you can practice on the [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-react-course/) and improve yourself.